# MonoGame - proper SpriteFont scaling

Tags: c#, fonts, scale, monogame

I'm making a GUI for my game and now I'm stuck on animations. I need to scale a font up when the mouse hovers over it and scale it down when it's not. Here's my code:

```
// Update()
if (!IsDisabled)
{
    elapsedSecondsFast = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 3;
    if (Size.Contains(InputManager.MouseRect))
    {
        scale += elapsedSecondsFast;
        if (scale >= 1.05f) scale = 1.05f;
    }
    else
    {
        scale -= elapsedSecondsFast;
        if (scale <= 1.0f) scale = 1.0f;
    }
}
// Draw()
if ((PrimaryFont != null) && (SecondaryFont != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)))
{
    if (IsHovered) TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, SecondaryFont, Text, new Vector2(TextRectangle.X, TextRectangle.Y), ForeColor, 0.0f, new Vector2((SecondaryFont.MeasureString(Text).X / 2 * scale - SecondaryFont.MeasureString(Text).X / 2), (SecondaryFont.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2 * scale - SecondaryFont.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2)), scale);
    else TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, PrimaryFont, Text, new Vector2(TextRectangle.X, TextRectangle.Y), ForeColor, 0.0f, new Vector2(PrimaryFont.MeasureString(Text).X / 2 * scale - PrimaryFont.MeasureString(Text).X / 2, (PrimaryFont.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2 * scale - PrimaryFont.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2)), scale);
}
```

The above is a `GUIElement` class which is inherited by my `Button` class. Let me explain my code briefly:

- `PrimaryFont` and `SecondaryFont` are 2 SpriteFonts that use the same
  font but a different size. This gives me the scale up/down animation I need without blurring my `PrimaryFont`.
- `TextRectangle` and `Size` are 2 different Rectangles. Since my button has a texture and text I decided not to draw text on the texture file but have the game position my text over the texture to "fake" the effect. So `TextRectangle` is the size and location of button text and `Size` is size and location of button texture. `TextRectangle` has its `center point` in the `center` of the `Button texture`. So far I have been using magic numbers to achieve this. This is the core of the problem here.
- You can see my `origin`, I passed it to the `DrawBorderedText` method of my `TextOutliner` class. The attributes are in the same order as if it were a `spriteBatch.DrawString()` call, only without `SpriteEffects` and `layerDepth`.

**The Problem**

Since I'm scaling the font (`origin = center` I think) it will no longer be in the center of the button. And since I have been using magic numbers to position the un-scaled text over the center of the button texture, I don't want to be forced to do the same thing for scaled text. I'm looking for an algorithm that would always position the text in the middle of my 270x72 texture, no matter if the text is scaled or not, while keeping the `scale` animation shown above, for ***each*** instance of the `Button` class. Preferably to have its origin point in the center.

**Edit**

So should I draw like this:

```
if (IsHovered) TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, SecondaryFont, Text, new Vector2(TextRectangle.X, TextRectangle.Y), ForeColor, 0.0f, new Vector2((SecondaryFont.MeasureString(Text).X / 2), (SecondaryFont.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2)), scale);
else TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, PrimaryFont, Text, new Vector2(TextRectangle.X, TextRectangle.Y), ForeColor, 0.0f, new Vector2(PrimaryFont.MeasureString(Text).X / 2, (PrimaryFont.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2)), scale);
```

and then draw the button's text at `btn.Size.Width / 2, btn.Size.Height / 2, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString("Play").X / 2, (int)MainGame.GameFontLarge.MeasureString("Play").Y / 2`

Comment: I don't think you need to scale the origin. Origin should just be measured size / 2

Comment: @LibertyLocked that breaks button positions for me. Also it seems the scale animation starts from top-left, I want it from center.

Comment: Draw the text in the middle/center of the button, then make origin measuredSize/2. It always scales from the origin.

Comment: I edited my question... Is this how to draw it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I eventually found the algorithm by myself and finally eliminated the need of using magic numbers for position of the text. Here's my technique:

```
TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, Font, Text, new Vector2(Size.X + ((Size.Width - Font.MeasureString(Text).X) / 2), Size.Y + ((Size.Height - Font.MeasureString(Text).Y)) / 2), ForeColor, 0.0f, new Vector2((Font.MeasureString(Text).X / 2 * scale - Font.MeasureString(Text).X / 2), (Font.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2 * scale - Font.MeasureString(Text).Y / 2)), scale);
```

I couldn't take the `scale` out of the `origin` equation as @LibertyLocked suggested, because the font was scaling from top-left point upon Mouse Hover and not the center as I want it to.

Comment: One tip (better readability and better performance): do the measuring in one step before drawing and place these values inside variables. It will be much easier to keep track of what's going on. After that, you should try to extract this into an extension method (e.g. `DrawStringCentered`) which accepts a `SpriteFont` and a `Rectangle`. If you have the need, you can then even extend this method to accept horizontal and vertical alignment parameters.